# Can you still use Application Loader to submit iOS programs to Apple?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 4.3.1.  I have a client that needs me to build an app for him and then allow him to submit (I am not the team agent so I cannot do it).  However, Xcode keeps building .xcarchive files instead of .ipa files.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

An AppStore ipa file is the `Payload` folder with a signed ipa file together with a valid iTunesArtwork file (512x512 px) compressed to a zip archive renamed to .ipa:

1. Folder

   `Payload` with a content:

   `myapp.app`

   `iTunesArtwork`
2. Archive `Payload` folder

   `Payload.zip`
3. Rename archive

   `myapp.ipa`

That .ipa file must be good for submission if you configure the build correctly, the client will have to set-up submission at iTunes connect and upload an ipa file there. Don't forget to keep a dsym file from the build, if that's lost you won't be able to symbolicate the crash logs for the client.

Comment: I don't see a Payload directory.  I see an Applications directory with a single .app file inside it.  Can I use "show contents" from the finder, copy out the Applications folder, then rename it to myapp.ipa and submit?

Comment: @gonzobrains you are to create a `Payload` directory yourself in any location, place .app itself and iTunesArtwork file there, archive folder and rename it to .ipa. The .app file must be configured & signed for app store submission.

Comment: @gonzobrains that is your png image without extension at filename, see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: It looks like just Icon.png is actually required.  Is there any easier way than doing this manually?

Comment: @gonzobrains sure, you can write a script/simple app to do it for you. it's not to hard to put an .app to Payload folder and zip it however :)

Comment: Well, I'd prefer Xcode just create the ipa and needed from the get-go.  You mentioned iTunesArtwork, but the link you provided says that's optional.  That link does, however, indicate that Icon.png is required.  I'd rather Xcode just package it up so I don't have to figure out what needs to go in the zip.  Yes, you're right.  It's not difficult to zip a few files provided I actually know what it supposed to be zipped in the first place.  Zipping didn't work for me the first time but I didn't know about the png file.  I'll try it again.  Thanks.

Comment: @gonzobrains as an admin you received a email describing the problem if the validation fails, this email usually has enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean I will have to try this process for myseld to see.  The whole reason I have this problem is that I am not the team agent and thus cannot see the errors. If I was I would just submit through xcode.